# How do I change an existing block to be nodequeue?

Tags: php, drupal

I'm drupal newbie and I'm living in terror now ;)
I've got an existing block on the site where you can see the newest articles.
I would like to make this block nodequeue, so I can decide which articles are gonna be there.

Is there a way to change block settings to be nodequeue or do i have to create new one and style it again?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on how you have created the block in the first place.

But the easiest thing will be to take the view that comes along with each node queue and setup the view to include a block.

*If you have the block as a view, you can add the node queue part, but you will have to do it in code, since the views UI isn't capable of it, so since you new to Drupal, this will probably be a bit to harry for you.*

Comment: You've written node query in your above answer a few times. You probably mean nodequeue

Comment: I didn't create the block, it was programmer before me ... no contact to him anymore. I'll try the easiest thing you write :) but im not sure if it's gonna work

Comment: @NoParrots: You can argue that you create node queues with the nodequeue module.

Comment: "But the easiest thing will be to take the view that comes along with each node query and setup the view to include a block." -- you have written "node query" and not nodequeue or node queue.